# In WinForms Application control + C is not doing a copy on my rich text box

Tags: .net, winforms, copy, richtextbox, paste

I added a menu with short cut keys for copy and past (Control+C & Control+V) on a windows forms application.  The application has a single richtextbox control.  The events for the menu items call RichTextBox.Copy and RichTextBox.Paste but I can't get the short cut keys to work.  Control+c & +v do nothing.

Is there a step I am missing?

Comment: could you show the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

Is the richtextbox ShortcutsEnabled property is set to true?
Try to remove the shortcut key from the menu and see if it works?